# Monte Carlo Sims - Please check my algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

Basically, the problem simulates the following:

There is an urn with 50 green balls and 50 red balls.

I am allowed to pick balls from the urn, without replacement, with the following rules: For every red ball picked, I lose a dollar, for every green ball picked, I gain a dollar.

I can stop picking whenever I want. Worst case scenario is I pick all 100, and net 0.

The question is to come up with an optimal stopping strategy, and create a program to compute the expected value of the strategy.

My strategy is to continue picking balls, while the expected value of picking another ball is positive.

That is, the stopping rule is DYNAMIC.

In Latex, here's the recursive formula in an image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnzYk.jpg

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



double ExpectedValue(double, double);
double max(double, double);

main() {

double g = 50;
double r = 50;


double EV = ExpectedValue(g, r);

printf ("%f\n\n", EV);

system("PAUSE");

}


double ExpectedValue(double g, double r){

double p =  (g / (g + r));

double q = 1 - p;

if (g == 0)

return r;

if (r == 0)

return 0;

double E_gr = max ((p * ExpectedValue (g - 1, r)) + (q * ExpectedValue (g, r - 1)), (r - g));

return E_gr; 

}

double max(double a, double b){

if (a > b)
return a;

else return b;
}
```

I let it run for 30 minutes, and it was still working. 
For small values of g and r, a solution is computed very quickly. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It's an interesting problem, but FWIW I'd go at it analytically rather than with a simulation.

Comment: "My strategy is to continue picking balls, while the expected value of picking another ball is positive." -- that's easy to answer. Don't play at all, since the expected value in the beginning is 0.

Comment: ...but you can do better than that. (interesting exercise for the reader)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm is fine, but you are wasting information. For a certain pair `(g, r)` you calculate it's ExpectedValue and then you throw that information away. Often with recursion algorithms remembering previously calculated values can speed it up a **LOT**.

The following code runs in the blink of an eye. For example for `g = r = 5000` it calculates `36.900218` in 1 sec. It remembers previous calculations of `ExpectedValue(g, r)` to prevent unnecessary recursion and recalculation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double ExpectedValue(int g, int r, double ***expectedvalues);
inline double max(double, double);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int g = 50;
    int r = 50;
    int i, j;

    double **expectedvalues = malloc(sizeof(double*) * (g+1));

    // initialise
    for (i = 0; i < (g+1); i++) {
        expectedvalues[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * (r+1));
        for (j = 0; j < (r+1); j++) {
            expectedvalues[i][j] = -1.0;
        }
    }

    double EV = ExpectedValue(g, r, &expectedvalues);
    printf("%f\n\n", EV);

    // free memory
    for (i = 0; i < (g+1); i++) free(expectedvalues[i]);
    free(expectedvalues);

    return 0;
}

double ExpectedValue(int g, int r, double ***expectedvalues) {
    if (g == 0) return r;
    if (r == 0) return 0;

    // did we calculate this before? If yes, then return that value
    if ((*expectedvalues)[g][r] != -1.0) return (*expectedvalues)[g][r];

    double p = (double) g / (g + r);
    double E_gr = max(p * ExpectedValue(g-1, r, expectedvalues) + (1.0-p) * ExpectedValue(g, r-1, expectedvalues), (double) (r-g));

    // store value for later lookup
    (*expectedvalues)[g][r] = E_gr;

    return E_gr;
}

double max(double a, double b) {
    if (a > b) return a;
    else return b;
}
```

Comment: @Evgeny Gavrin: I explained what I am doing in the introduction. Also, the user doesn't seem to be learning C, but exploring algorithms. And IMO some example code how to face a problem is extremely helpful.

Comment: Yes, you've used some functions I wasn't familiar with, but I'm reading up on them, and learning how to improve efficiency in my algorithms. Very helpful information from both of you. This isn't a homework assignment on which I'll be graded. It's to get my feet wet with simulation. Thank you!

Comment: @nightcracker: I've read up on pointers, and am trying to figure out exactly how you are storing the info in the array. The code doesn't compile in dev-c++. Are you creating a 3-dim array?

Comment: @IniquiTrance: No, I'm creating a 2-dim array that I pass around with pointers. What error do you get from dev-c++?

Comment: @nightcracker: 

'double expectedvalues = malloc(sizeof(double*) * (g+1)); (invalid conversion from void* to double**) 

and: expectedvalues[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * (r+1)); ((invalid conversion from void*' to double*') –

Comment: @IniquiTrance: You are probably using a C++ compiler, instead of a C one. Between the `=` and the `malloc` sign add this: `(double**)` for the first and `(double*)` for the second.

Comment: @nightcracker: Ahh, thanks very much, I used a C compiler. I'm wondering though, why did you have ExpectedValue() use ***expectedvalues? Doesn't that have 3 pointer arrays?

Comment: No, it's a pointer to an array of pointers to doubles. So it's basicly a pointer to a 2d array.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, correct, but rather straightforward solution.

Here's what you can do:

- Eliminate recursion!
- Eliminate recalulations of `ExpectedValue`
- Parallelize your code
- Read this [[lecture notes]](http://cc.oulu.fi/~tf/tiedostot/pub/montecarlo/lectures/mc_notes2.pdf). It definitely will be useful

I can provide some code samples, but it'd not be fair.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly speaking, adding one ball to the urn doubles the number of calls you will have to make to `ExpectedValue` (let's not quibble about boundary conditions). This is called O(e<sup>n</sup>), and it can bring the most powerful computer on Earth to its knees.

The problem is that you are calculating the same values over and over again. Keep a table of `ExpectedValue(r,g)` and fill it in as you go, so that you never have to calculate the same value more than once. Then you'll be working in O(n<sup>2</sup>), which is heck of a lot faster.